# Executing F# scripts

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to practice my F# by writing small console scripts in F# in place of my usual method of writing shell scripts/batch files. I currently run them using "fsi script.fsx [args]". Is there a way I can associate these fsx files with fsi so that I can run them directly like "script.fsx [args]"?

Comment: Although writing simple script files and running them is definitely an option, I think that it is much easier to learn F# if you use F# Interactive from Visual Studio. You can start by creating a new "F# Script" (File -> New -> File...) and then start writing some code (in an assorted order). Then you can select some part of the code and evaluate it in the F# Interactive window by perssing [Alt]+[Enter].

Comment: @Tomas - I think he means he's writing the scripts as practice for writing real code that does actual things, while fulfilling a need he has at the same time (it seems he writes a lot of scripts)

Comment: Tomas: One thing that wasn't clear from your description: you still need to manually open the F# Interactive window for the Alt-Enter trick to work.  But what a nice trick!  Thank you!

Comment: Tomas is right, use Visual Studio. There is no Express version for F#, but you can download the Shell, and install F# 'on top' of that.

Comment: Have you checked out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003963/how-to-get-f-scripts-files-and-other-script-languages-to-work-like-exe-cmd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

There are two keys here:

1. You need to bind an application to execute to the ".fsx" extension. The exact way to do this may vary a bit between operating system versions (I have only done this in the past by editing the registry directly, so I can't provide a generic solution here); make sure the command to be executed does include the script arguments (as `%*`), so the shell\open\command entry in the registry for the binding should look like

   `"c:\Program Files\FSharp-1.9.9.9\bin\fsi.exe" "@%1" %*`

   See Gradbot's response for more details.
2. You may want to add the extension you want to trigger script execution (".fsx" in this case) to the PATHEXT environment variable, so CMD.exe can find the script even without you specifying the script's extension. A warning: if you are concerned about your system's security, reconsider this step - the fact that VBScripts are registered on a default Windows XP and older systems to provide a similar feature has been exploited in the past by virus writers (I don't know if this is still true on Vista or windows 7).

Comment: You can also use the "ftype" and "assoc" commands at the command line (at least in all the versions of Windows I've tried) to accomplish #1.

Answer (score 4):

As there are no answers so far, I'll try to turn my earlier comment into an answer with some more details.

I just tried to create a standard windows association for ***.fsx** files to open them automatically in **fsi.exe** and it works with no problems - when you open the **fsx** file, it runs F# Interactive and automatically evaluates the content of the file. This corresponds to running the command:

```
> fsi.exe test.fsx
```

However, I think that it is much easier to learn F# by using F# Interactive from Visual Studio. Even if you don't have a licence, you can use [Visual Studio Shell with the free F# plugin](http://www.11011.net/fsharp-in-visual-studio-express). I think SharpDevelop also provides similar integration (but probably not with some limitations).

The easiest way to start is to create a new "F# Script" (*File -> New -> File...*) and then start writing some code (in an assorted order). Then you can select some part of the code and evaluate it in the F# Interactive window by perssing `[Alt] + [Enter]`. You'll first need to open the F# Interactive window, which can be done using `[Ctrl] + [Alt] + [F]` or you can find it in the *View -> Other Windows* menu item.

I think most of the F# webcasts use F# Interactive in this way, so if you look at some of them, you should get a good idea how to use it. Look for example at [How Do I?](http://fsharp.net/) videos at [www.fsharp.net](http://fsharp.net/) or [F# videos at Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/FSharp).

Comment: I think he is trying to replace batch files with F# scripts (which is he was asking if there is a way to just point to an fsx file).  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old but... Although I complete agree with everyone who suggests doing REPL-based development, if you find you've written a nice reusable script then here is what works well on Linux and MacOS. Put the `*.fsx` script in your ~/bin folder or wherever and do the usual *shebang* trick that you do with other scripts:

First make your script

```ml
#!/usr/bin/env dotnet fsi
    
printfn $"1 + 1 = {1 + 1}"
```

make it executable and run it

```sh
chmod 755 foo.fsx
$ ./foo.fsx 
1 + 1 = 2
```

Comment: Just a note that on my debian machine, i needed to use `#!/usr/bin/env -S dotnet fsi`. ("The ‘-S’ option instructs ‘env’ to split the single string into
multiple arguments.)

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "executing F# scripts on ubuntu" makes you land here.

To execute .fsx scripts with Mac/Linux, write `fsharpi yourScript.fsx`, for windows users write: `fsi yourScript.fsx`

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/9154-default-programs-associate-file-type-protocol.html) a walk through on setting the association in windows 7.