# Running F# script in Windows seamlessly as powershell script

Tags: f#-scripting

In Windows, given a PowerShell script script1.ps1 and a command or PowerShell prompt, starting the script is just a matter of writing its name an enter in the keyboard:

```
> .\script1.ps1 <parameters>
```

To run an f# script (.fsx), we need to prepend the script name with the interactive command:

```
> dotnet fsi script1.fsx <parameters>
```

I am looking for a way to configure Windows (not Linux) so that I can start an F# script directly as I do with PowerShell:

```
.\script1.fsx <parameters>
```

The closest SO post on the topic is [Executing F# scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459472/executing-f-scripts), however I couldn't make it work with the information in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, maybe there are better ways:

- Create runfsx.bat, with the following content

`dotnet fsi %*`

- Associate one .fsx file with runfsx.bat (this results in associating all .fsx files)

[image]

- Using regedit, search for runfsx.bat (should find Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\runfsx.bat), then drill down to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\runfsx.bat\shell\open\command and change the command as desired (e.g. "C:\Root\Tools\runfsx.bat" "%1" %*)

[image]